# What is the best compression using php in terms of speed

Tags: php, html

I want to use compression so that i can speedup my website.Which is the best compression available? Is compression using **ob_start("ob_gzhandler");** the best? Does it compress the images embedded.Is there a way to compress those images?

**P.S: I don't have access to the server configuration. I only have a FTP account**

Comment: .htaccess files might still work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the webserver's functions for that.  If you use apache, you can check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html for instance.

Comment: But what would happen if they are both enabled? If you host enables it, you might slow it down by recompressing?

Comment: I dun have any access to server,and its a shared server used by many so installing mod over server is next to impossible. I want the best result out of what i have i.e. using script to compress,like gzip

Comment: Yes, you said that, but I meant that you still have to check if the host HAS it enabled and check if it will enable sometimes in the future, because you don't want to double compress your data.

Comment: If it's shared hosting I'd guess your webhoster probably already has deflate configured. If not, you should ask him to do so. Doing this in php is subpar.

Comment: how can i test whether its enabled or not from my end?

Comment: You can fish it from the headers probably, but there are some sites out there that help you. Random google says [this site](http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/compression) but its not the prettiest (lots of ads and all). I guess it'll do.

Comment: Compression status:  Uncompressed

Comment: Too bad :(. I know of no other php methods then the one you mention, but you can check out [this blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance.html) for some tips on .js and .css compression without access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` is the best you can get if you don't control the server.

The difference between various methods is mainly in efficiency, e.g. some servers or reverse proxies are able to cache compressed data to avoid re-compressing them again. However, gzip is very fast for today's hardware, so even most basic compression in PHP is going to be a net gain.

You should also compress your JS and CSS files, **but** you shouldn't do that by simply wrapping them in a PHP script, because by default PHP makes files non-cacheable. Any gain from compression will be lost when browsers are forced re-download those files over and over again.

Ideally you should either use a CDN that will compress them for you or ask your host to enable server-level compression for static text files.

Answer (score 0):

No, ob_gzhandler doesn't compress images if you just provide a link in your HTML. Only if you load them into a PHP file as binary data, like with file_get_contents().

Comment: gzipping of images doesn't make sense anyway, because images have their own compression already, so HTTP-level gzip won't reduce their size and will only add overhead.